# Run docker file but says port already taken

Tags: apache, docker, dockerfile

So I was able to build on my MacBook: `docker build -t my-first-demo` .
But then when I tried to run the app: `docker run -p 80:80 my-first-demo`
it gives me the error:

> Error response from daemon: Ports are not available: port is already allocated.
>   ERRO[0000] error waiting for container: context canceled

I changed the port to things like 81:80, but still not working:

> AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.17.0.2. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.2-apache
COPY src/ /var/www/html/
EXPOSE 80
```

And a simple php file:

```php
<?php
    echo "Hello, World";
?>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: AH00558 is not an error, it is just a warning, your container should work after that

Comment: but when i go to localhost, the webpage still shows what originally my localhost is showing, not the hello world in this php

Comment: Because, if you change the port, then you have to access localhost on that port... given `81:80` you will have to access _http://localhost:81/_

Comment: yeah, localhost:81 is forbidden :Apache/2.4.38 (Debian) Server at localhost Port 81. I guess I do need to shot down apache first

Comment: 81 might be a reserved port. 8080 is the "official" child http port, give it a shot also

Comment: I stop apache, and rebuild the docker and run with: docker run -p 80:80 my-first-demo, but when I go to localhost, it is forbidden saying apache is using 80

Comment: Ah, never mind. It worked, I named the file wrong. It should be index.php. I had it as Index,php. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the command

```
docker ps -a
```

to see that allocated port. Also check if any other process is using it with:

```
sudo lsof -i:80
```

In order to run another container in that same port you should stop any container in used port with:

```
docker kill <container id> or <container name>
```

Use tab keyboard and docker will list available active container names.

Comment: Thank you. When I did docker ps -a, there is nothing under PORTS. I wonder what is going on.

Comment: check  my updates . if you want you can insert your output of "docker ps" and "sudo lsof -i:80" in your question to have more info.

Comment: Thank you. There is only a COMMAND: httpd using PID 84 by root along with othr process. No one is using the port 80.

Comment: if you have a pid 84 using that port , it means the process 84 is using the port 80. Otherwise the command I told you should be empty. Port 80 is typically used by webservers, so easilly could be used by some other process.

Comment: @GavinHoang you have apache running on your local machine. So Docker cannot use this port anymore.

Comment: I know that whenever I type localhost in the browser, it shows something like hello world in default, but that file is from the /Library/WebServer/.... Is it because of that? Because the localhost is using 80?

Comment: @ β.εηοιτ.βε yes, that's also what I figured. Is there anyway I can switch to Docker and switch back whenever I want it?

Comment: What OS are you on? Mac? Linux?

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε Mac Book Pro 2017

Comment: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-macosx-starting-stopping-apache-web-server/

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε Oh right, how come I forgot that. Thanks a lot. I will give it a shot.